# Performance Graphic in R, comparing two different years using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to do a graphic to compare the different year, similar to this using ggplot2: [image]

Using this dataset:

```
    Estado  Posição Ano
São Paulo   1   2017
Santa Catarina  2   2017
Paraná  3   2017
Distrito Federal    4   2017
Mato Grosso do Sul  5   2017
Minas Gerais    6   2017
Rio Grande do Sul   7   2017
Espirito Santo  8   2017
Rio de Janeiro  9   2017
Paraiba     10  2017
Ceará   11  2017
Mato Grosso     12  2017
Goiás   13  2017
Roraima 14  2017
Rio Grande do Norte 15  2017
Tocantins   16  2017
Rondônia    17  2017
Pernanbuco  18  2017
Acre    19  2017
Bahia   20  2017
Pará    21  2017
Amazonas    22  2017
Piauí   23  2017
Alagoas 24  2017
Maranhão    25  2017
Amapá   26  2017
Sergipe 27  2017
São Paulo   1   2018
Santa Catarina  2   2018
Paraná  4   2018
Distrito Federal    3   2018
Mato Grosso do Sul  7   2018
Minas Gerais    6   2018
Rio Grande do Sul   5   2018
Espirito Santo  8   2018
Rio de Janeiro  13  2018
Paraiba     9   2018
Ceará   12  2018
Mato Grosso     11  2018
Goiás   10  2018
Roraima 18  2018
Rio Grande do Norte 19  2018
Tocantins   15  2018
Rondônia    14  2018
Pernanbuco  20  2018
Acre    27  2018
Bahia   22  2018
Pará    23  2018
Amazonas    17  2018
Piauí   21  2018
Alagoas 16  2018
Maranhão    26  2018
Amapá   24  2018
Sergipe 25  2018
```

I tried to use this code (in commentaries):

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(grid) 
ggplot(an.18.19.a, aes(x = Ano, y = Posição, group = Estado, label = Estado)) + 
geom_path(aes(x = Ano), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc")), size = 1, color = "green") + 
geom_text(size = 1) + 
theme_minimal() + 
theme(axis.title = element_blank(), 
      axis.text = element_blank(), 
      axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
      panel.grid = element_blank())
```

But unfortunately, didn't work, anyone have a suggestion to help-me, please?

Comment: The code and data in your question outputs a plot which is somewhat similar to your example plot. So what do you mean by "didn't work" ? Just that the output is not what you would like?

Comment: The chart is called a slopegraph (or slope graph), and web search for that term plus "ggplot2" will return several useful tutorials [such as this one](https://datascienceplus.com/creating-slopegraphs-with-r/).

Comment: Perfect, I appreciate your comment...  I needed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started, with output similar to the example.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

an.18.19.a %>% 
  arrange(Estado, Ano) %>% 
  group_by(Estado) %>% 
  mutate(Change = case_when(Posição < lead(Posição) ~ 1, 
                            Posição > lead(Posição) ~ -1, 
                            TRUE ~ 0), 
         Change = sum(Change, na.rm = TRUE), 
         Ano = factor(Ano)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(Ano, Posição), Posição)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(Change))) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = Estado, color = factor(Change))) + 
  geom_text(data = filter(an.18.19.a, Ano == 2017), 
            aes(label = paste(Estado, Posição)), size = 2, nudge_x = -0.1, hjust = 1) + 
  geom_text(data = filter(an.18.19.a, Ano == 2018), 
            aes(label = paste(Posição, Estado)), size = 2, nudge_x = 0.1, hjust = 0) + 
  scale_y_reverse() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "grey", "red")) + 
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(), 
        axis.text = element_blank(), 
        axis.title = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        panel.border = element_blank()) + 
  guides(color = FALSE)
```

Result:

[image]